# Perturbation theory in quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory

This question concerns the quantum harmonic oscillator:

(a)Express the operator $\hat B = \hat x \hat p + \hat p \hat x + \hbar$ in terms of $\hat a_{\pm}$ and $\hbar$

(b)Write the matrix representation for $\hat B$, truncated to a $4 \times 4$ matrix using eigenstates up to and including $n=3$

(c)A perturbation of $\gamma \hat B$ is applied to a QHO, where $\gamma$ is a small constant. Find the first order correction to the energies, and hence provide a condition for $\gamma$ that will make the perturbation "small".

Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track (I'm particularly confused about part (c)):

(a) I re-expressed as $\hat B = i\hbar+2\hat p \hat x+\hbar=i\hbar + \frac{i\hbar}{2}(\hat a_+-\hat a_-)(\hat a_++\hat a_-)+\hbar$

(b) By computing $<m|\hat B|n>$, where $m,n$ are eigenstates of the original QHO, and applying actions of the raising/lowering operators, I got the matrix:
$$\hbar\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -i\sqrt2 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & -i\sqrt6\\i\sqrt2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & i\sqrt6 & 0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

(c) Having got the matrix above (assuming that it is correct), is the first order correction just $<n|\hat B|n>$, i.e. the values down the diagonal? So it would be $\gamma \hbar$ for all $n$? What condition on $\gamma$ is required to make the perturbation small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the eigenvalues are not degenerate, the correction to the energy level $E_n$ is just $\langle n | \gamma B | n \rangle $. It's easy to see that the correction $\delta E_n$ is $\gamma \hbar$ for all $n$. The correction is good if 
$$
\frac{\delta E_n}{E_n}\ll 1
$$
That's
$$
\frac{\gamma}{\omega(n+\frac{1}{2})}\ll 1
$$
For all $n$.
And this is guaranteed if
$$
\frac{\gamma}{\omega}\ll 1
$$
(in particular we need $\gamma/\omega \leq 1/2 $ )Because for $n\geq 1$
$$
\frac{\gamma}{\omega(n+\frac{1}{2})}\leq \frac{\gamma}{\omega}\ll 1
$$
And for $n=0$
$$
\frac{2\gamma}{\omega} \ll 1
$$
If $\gamma/\omega \ll 1$ (because we talk about at least one order of magnitude with the symbol $\ll$).

Comment: could you expand a little on how you obtain $\frac{\gamma}{\omega}$? The lower bound on $E_n$ should be $\frac12 \hbar \omega$ no? so should't it be $\frac{2\gamma}{\omega}<<1$? Although it would be same order of magnitude

Comment: @Alex is it ok now?

Comment: yes you can put $\frac{2\gamma}{\omega}\ll 1$ but is the same because with the symbol $\ll$ we talk about a factor $10$ at least.